# Rails in Windows vs Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, bundler, javascript

I have recently installed `ruby 2.0.0p247` and `rails 4.0.0` in both windows and linux .

But after giving `rails new Myapp` and `bundle install` .

I can start it using `rails s` in windows without any issue , but whereas in linux am getting javascript runtime error which can be solved by addding `gem 'therubyracer'` (or uncommenting out) in Gemfile.

My question is how come it is working in windows but not in linux until I manually add therubyracer to it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails depends on [execjs](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs) to provide an javascript runtime environment.

Execjs will use the native javascript runtime if one is provided by host OS. This is the case for MacOSX (it has JavascriptCore) and on Windows (it has JScript).

On linux, there's no "default js engine", which quite makes sense since linux is just a set of drivers. The desktop environment you will add on top of the kernel and baselayout is up to you. So is the javascript implementation you will use. The two most common are node.js and rhino (the mozilla js interpreter).

Therubyracer is actually just a gem embedding a binary copy of v8, the engine behind node.js .

Comment: Thanks , I got it now